# Phing not working on OSX / MAMP

Tags: php, macos, mamp, phing

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/
> ./pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
> ./pear install phing/phing
```

Installation ran.
I can run the following:

```
> ./pear/ info phing/phing

About pear.phing.info/phing-2.4.0
=================================
Release Type          PEAR-style PHP-based Package
Name                  phing
```

If I Run the command

```
>ls -al
```

Phing is not listed.

You can now run this command:

```
> ./phing -h
-bash: ./phing: No such file or directory
> phing
-bash: phing: command not found
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its a path problem. Try to check where phing is:

```
locate phing
```

or even, if you have some time:

```
find / -name "phing"
```

Then, if you find it, you may add it's path to your .profile file:

```
echo "export PATH=/path/to/phing/:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: the 
>find / -name "phing" 

Helped my find the answer I was looking for! Thanks!